# Case-insensitive flag i doesn't work in Jquery filter by data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to filter a list according to a search string. The whole thing must be case-insensitive.

As you can see in the snippet, the `i` flag for case-insensitivity works in a normal Jquery selector, but not in the filter selector. Is this a bug or is there something wrong with my code?

```js
var searchString = 't';

// WORKS
$('li[data-number*="' + searchString + '" i]').css('border', '1px solid red');

// SAME SELECTOR BUT DOESN'T WORK
$('li').filter('li[data-number*="' + searchString + '" i]').css('background', 'lightcoral');
```

```html
<ul>

  <li data-number="One">First</li>
  <li data-number="Two">Second</li>
  <li data-number="Three">Third</li>
  <li data-number="Four">Fourth</li>


</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector in the `filter()` method doesn't accept flags in the same way that a selector provided to the jQuery object constructor does.

The workaround is to provide a function to `filter()` which you can use to convert the strings to the same case before comparison:

```js
var searchString = 't';

$('li').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('number').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) != -1;
}).css('background', 'lightcoral');
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-number="One">First</li>
  <li data-number="Two">Second</li>
  <li data-number="Three">Third</li>
  <li data-number="Four">Fourth</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm sure you're right but that's quite weird.

Comment: I've never heard of a flags in selectors, and can't find any mention of it in the documentation.

Comment: @Barmar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: That's DOM selectors, not jQuery. Does jQuery get them automatically from the DOM?

Comment: I believe the Sizzle engine will use whatever it can natively. Therefore it's possible that using flags in IE and Edge will break, as they don't support it.

Comment: In fact, it does. Curiosity got the better of me and I just tested it in Edge. You get this error from the OPs first example: `SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: li[data-number*="t" i]`